# Reading static resources from source directory

Tags: tomcat, web, intellij-idea

I have maven project in intellij. Sometimes I work on javascript only - it is single page application. For that case I want that my configured tomcat instance read js and other static resources from my source disrectory. I realized that by creating file in conf/catalina/localhost whene I setup docBase  but... Firts: my java webservice using spring, generally it is java code that require tomcat architecture - means to be compilled and placed in right place. When I work only on static javascript I run tomcat from install directory, commenting spring config in web.xml. It works right but it is ugly. I'm searching for solution  the best using only intellij: server that only servicing static js, html filres from source directory.

EDIT1

I found that maven tomcat plugin 2 with tomcat 7 serving static content from source directory.

EDIT2

Additional php 4.4 has possibility run as standalone server, it is only one short line to run it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use a server like nginx or NodeJS connect to serve static resources directly from the sources, and serve as a proxy to tomcat for dynamic resources. This way, when working on static resources only, I don't need to deploy anything to tomcat to test my changes.